# viz.jsの入手方法について

Tags: graphviz

windows7でviz.jsを使用したいのですが、[このGitHub](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/)の説明を見ても理解できません。"Getting Viz.js" および "Building From Source" 部分をもう少し詳細に説明して戴けないでしょうか。

Comment: 少なくとも「ここからダウンロードできるよ」って書いてあるので，どこで詰まっておられるかがわかると回答がつきやすいかもしれません．[これ](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/wiki/Usage) も参考になるでしょうか

Comment: JacaScriptのviz.jsライブラリが欲しいだけなのですが、それをダウンロードしても動かないので質問を投稿した次第です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using a script Tag](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/wiki/Usage#using-a-script-tag)と同様の使い方であれば、`viz.js`と`full.render.js`が必要になります。

[Getting Viz.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/#getting-vizjs)に記載の[releases page](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/releases)へ移動すると、[full.render.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/releases/download/v2.0.0/full.render.js)
と[viz.js](https://github.com/mdaines/viz.js/releases/download/v2.0.0/viz.js)のリンクがあるのでそれらをダウンロードすれば利用できるはずです。

Comment: ご指摘の通りやってみましたが、残念ながら動作しません。"TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function"とのエラーが発生します。現在は、或るサイトで使用している viz.js を使用して

Comment: 確認済みのソースで行っております。

Comment: v1.8で動作を確認しました。v2.0ではv1.8のソースが動作しませんでしたが、これは別問題として、最初の問題は解決しました。